# Simple word riddles

Tags: word

These are just quick little ones that I was told (and stumped) by my nephew.

A (very) basic knowledge of the english language is required to solve them (apologies to the international audience).

First:

> What begins with 'e', ends with 'e' and has a single letter in it?

Second:

> What begins with 'p', ends with 'e' and has thousands of letters in it?

Comment: Reminds me of the old, what start with * and end with *** riddle/jokes ;P

Comment: For the first one I was going to say that the answer was simply `e`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What begins with 'e', ends with 'e' and has a single letter in it?

> An **e**nvelop**e**! 
>  
>  Alternatively: An **e**ating establishment's rating scor**e**

What begins with 'p', ends with 'e' and has thousands of letters in it?

> A **p**ost offic**e**!

Answer (score 7):

An alternate solution

What begins with 'e', ends with 'e' and has a single letter in it?

> An **'extreme single character estimate'**

What begins with 'p', ends with 'e' and has thousands of letters in it?

> A **Petabyte**, can store much much more than merley thousands of letters

Comment: I can't say this is the official one, but I do like it a lot more than the canontical one, and its a lot more relevant to me, good on you.

Answer (score 0):

Could the answer to the second riddle be

> A **'p**ost offic**e'**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This riddle has already been solved and an answer accepted, so I'm afraid your answer doesn't really add anything...

Comment: Whoops, I was browsing on mobile and missed the second part of the answer, only saw the petabyte answer.

Answer (score -1):

Envelope. Eye is a potential alternative.
SECOND questions answer is **-postal service**

Comment: First of all, welcome to Puzzling.SE. I'd like to point out that adding an answer to a question that's already been given (and accepted) months ago, adds little value and is actually discouraged.

Comment: Welcome!  I would agree with @TimCouwelier, though, perhaps with the explanation that the homophone "I" has only one letter, your alternative to part one might be worth noting.  Also, some of us on Puzzling.SE like to use >! to obscure any spoilers that might be our answers.

Comment: ok i didnt notice see will see from now on just joined this group